# Saving initial number calculated in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem which I kindly need help with in python. I have a calculation in a for loop that outputs answers that constantly changes.

I would like to save the first value calculated in the loop in an array or something similar so I will be able to use it later in the script. I tried looking for help online but nothing has worked so far.

The code looks like this

```
for face in faces:

    x,y,w,h = face
    ss = 2.8*57*480
    BB = h*3.60
    F = ss/BB
    print ('Distance = ', F)
```

Comment: I can't see any loop in your code, it's somehow difficult to understand exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm thinking all you may need is: `return x` if this is in a function. Otherwise, you're not changing the value of `x` so technically it is "saved". Otherwise all I I have left to reason is you mean save to a file then you'll need to just simply search something like "how to save a value to file in python" there's tons of resources out there for this.

Comment: Do you only want to save the first value in the loop? I suppose you can use an if-statement and assign the first result to a variable or array. But why use a loop at all if you only are going to use the first result?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The actual code is a face detection system. I want to use the change in the height of the detected object to find out how much the object has moved. In the full code h is constantly changing. What I would like to do is get the initial value and find the difference with the current value.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all values using a generator expression, save the first then print them all.

```
import itertools

ss = 2.8 * 57 * 480
distances = (ss / h*3.6 for _, _, _, h in faces)

saved_distance = next(distances, None)  # the None prevents an error if `faces` is empty
for distance in itertools.chain([saved_distance], distances):
    print(f"Distance = {distance}")
```

Comment: I have implemented this and tried to just print out the first value because that is what I am interested in for now but could not do it. Please how do I just store the initial calculated value and print. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Dave1 `saved_distance` is the first value

Comment: That is what I also thought but it keeps printing a new value for saved_distance when there is a change in the value for h

Comment: `saved_distance` isn't a generator, it's a generated value. It can't be changing :). Your code must not reflect mine.

Comment: my code is very similar to yours. Could it be because this part of the code is in a while loop it keeps changing ? I tried pasting my code in here to show you but the format does no look good.

Comment: Thank you, I have now uploaded my code there : https://gist.github.com/fy15nadz/7b56a2f286e84f9c68aef5f49fc1cf42